# CloudWatch alarm moving back to OK based on historic data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CloudWatch Alarm that checks all data points over a 60 minute window, and if 5 of those data points have Problems then the CloudWatch Alarm is moved into an Alarm state.
This works correctly and the output from CloudWatch shows which data points have presented with Problems:

```
Message = {"AlarmName":"Test Alarm","AlarmDescription":"Test Alarm","AWSAccountId":"xxxxxxxxxx","NewStateValue":"ALARM","NewStateReason":"Threshold Crossed: 5 out of the last 5 datapoints were greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0). The most recent datapoints which crossed the threshold: [1.0 (02/08/20 10:11:00), 4.0 (02/08/20 09:56:00), 2.0 (02/08/20 09:41:00), 2.0 (02/08/20 09:26:00), 1.0 (02/08/20 09:11:00)] (minimum 5 datapoints for OK -> ALARM transition).","StateChangeTime":"2020-08-02T10:26:48.505+0000","Region":"Asia Pacific (Sydney)","AlarmArn":"xxxxxxx","OldStateValue":"OK","Trigger":{"MetricName":"Problem","Namespace":"xxxxx","StatisticType":"Statistic","Statistic":"MAXIMUM","Unit":null,"Dimensions":[{"value":"default","name":"environment"}],"Period":900,"EvaluationPeriods":5,"ComparisonOperator":"GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold","Threshold":1.0,"TreatMissingData":"- TreatMissingData: missing","EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile":""}}
```

The issue I am facing is when transitioning back to the OK state. From looking at the CloudWatch output when transitioning back to the OK it shows the following:

```
{"AlarmName":"Test Alarm","AlarmDescription":"Test Alarm","AWSAccountId":"xxxxxxxxx","NewStateValue":"OK","NewStateReason":"Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 5 datapoints [0.0 (02/08/20 09:27:00)] was not greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for ALARM -> OK transition).","StateChangeTime":"2020-08-02T10:27:48.489+0000","Region":"Asia Pacific (Sydney)","AlarmArn":"xxxxxxxx","OldStateValue":"ALARM","Trigger":{"MetricName":"Problem","Namespace":"xxxxxxx","StatisticType":"Statistic","Statistic":"MAXIMUM","Unit":null,"Dimensions":[{"value":"default","name":"environment"}],"Period":900,"EvaluationPeriods":5,"ComparisonOperator":"GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold","Threshold":1.0,"TreatMissingData":"- TreatMissingData: missing","EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile":""}}
```

The bit that stands out to me here is:

```
Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 5 datapoints [0.0 (02/08/20 09:27:00)] was not greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0)
```

I am understanding this to mean that, if any of the last 5 data points did not cross the threshold, then move the alarm back to an OK state. This is not how I would want my Alarm to behave.

What I would like to do is have it move back to an OK state only if NEW data points do not breach the Problem threshold.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistake your alarm will look only at data points for 60 minutes. So once this window is finished, a new one will begin, and if you do not take the old data point into your new window, the alarm will switch to OK because none of the new data points of that new time window will have crossed the threshold

Comment: I would assume that CloudWatch uses a rolling timer and checks if the criteria within that rolling hour matches, which is fine. Based on how CloudWatch phrases its messages: 1 out of the last 5 datapoints was not greater than or equal to the threshold

I think you are incorrect.